# Linq - Narrow down a list object of events by tags within

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm a little bit stumped with this Linq statement. My basic database structure is:

- Event (ID, Name, VenueID)
- Venue (ID, Name)
- EventTag (EventID, TagID)
- VenueTag (VenueID, TagID)
- Tag (TagID, Name)

I have a list of events, and I want to narrow it down by events that either contain the specified tag, or the venue they are held at contain the tag.

I have tried this, and I think I may not be too far off, but I'm still struggling to get it to work:

```
eventsList = eventsList
                .SelectMany(x => x.EventTag)
                .Where(et => et.TagID == tagID)
                .Select(et => t.Event)
                .Union(eventsList.SelectMany(x=>x.Venue.VenueTag)
                .Where(vt =>vt.TagID == tagID)
                .Select(vt=>vt.Venue.Event)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
```

I'd be very grateful for any help!

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Any` for this:

```
eventsList.Where(
              x => x.EventTag.Any(et => et.TagID == tagID)
                   || x.Venue.Any(v => v.Any(vt => vt.TagID == tagID)))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still just picking up on some of these things like "Any".